# Push Sold Out Products to End of Results

Tags: magento2, algolia

I'd like my Magento 2 in stock products to display in Algolia search results before my out of stock products. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version (1.0.3) it's not possible via Algolia configuration in Magento, because `in_stock` attribute is not exposed in Algolia configuration in Magento backend.

But it'll be possible in upcoming version (>= 1.0.4), which should be released early next week. In the new version, you will need to select `in_stock` attribute as indexable attribute and then use this attribute for custom ranking.
That will ensure, that products with the same textual relevancy will be sorted based on custom ranking and in stock products will be ranked higher then out of stock ones. You can find more about custom ranking in Algolia documentation: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/relevance/ranking#custom-ranking

The configuration then might look like this:
[image]

P.S.
Here is the pull request which exposes the `in_stock` attribute - https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento-2/pull/109

Feel free to give it a try!